# SDL2 - cannot find lsdlmain and lsdl. Codeblocks

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

I just started fooling around with SDL2 using Lazy Foo's tutorial and I'm having some issues. When building I get two errors:

cannot find lsdl

cannot find lsdlmain

Now... of course it can't find those because they are not in the lib folder I linked. I only have lsdl2main and lsdl2. I put the SDL2.dll in my project folder and did everything as Lazy Foo said, yet I still have this issue. I did manage to bypass this issue by copying the lsdl2 and lsdl2main from the lib folder and changing them to lsdl and lsdlmain. Now I have both lsdl/lsdlmain and lsdl2/lsdlmain ... even though they are the same libraries. I don't think this is ok, this is why I'm asking the question. What is the proper way to solve this? I read on lazy foo something about the compiler picking 32-bit libs over 64-bit , but I am using the 32-bit ones from the 32-bit folder, so I'm not sure if that is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is just use `sdl2main` and `sdl2` instead of obsolete `sdlmain` and `sdl` in your linker options. Lazy Foo's tutorials are obsolete and obviously require some corrections if you intend to use SDL2 instead of SDL 1.x which is the version tutorials are based on.

Comment: oh no, he updated his tutorials for SDL2. http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php

Comment: @Ryncops Did you follow [step 6](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php#6) correctly? _Go under Linker Settings and paste -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_

Comment: @gurka yes, i did everything as shown. it links perfectly to lsdl2main and lsdl2

Comment: @Ryncops well, what is the problem then? Or the issue is resolved?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. I just copied lsdl2main back into the lib folder but under another name (lsdlmain). So I now have both lsdl2main and lsdlmain, but they actually are the same library aka lsdl2main. Everything seems to work fine though, my program compiles.

Comment: @Ryncops I guess the question is why your linker is trying to find _lsdl_ and _lsdlmain_ when you have specified _lsdl2_ and _lsdl2main_. Do you have a full build log of the problem? You should not need to copy/rename any libraries at all.

Comment: @Ryncops @gurka is right, if you did it all properly you should not rename anything, `lsdl2main` is basically means link file named `sdl2main.lib`. There is little to go wrong here, just double check you did all correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a year old but I hope this still helps someone struggling to find an answer. If you were following Lazy Foo's tutorial "setting up SDL" on Code Blocks, you might have accidentally opened his old tutorial via Google.  http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/ instead of http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/ which has the updated instructions.

His old one shows that you have to fill out -lsdl and -lsdlmain on the Global Compiler's linker which is under Settings> Compiler.. > Linker Settings. Then you somehow opened his new tutorial which shows you to to fill -lSDL2main -lSDL2 under the Build option's linker.

Just check if your Global Compiler's linker or your Build Option's linker settings are correct. Setting -lSDL2main -lSDL2 flags on either one should work.